# iSeries/as400 Binding Directories I have to fix a program. I need the field type and length

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have to fix a program. I need the field type and length.

Is it possible to list procedures from a service program and the field types/lengths of the entry fields?

Answer (score 1):

What are you actually trying to do?

The short answer to your question is no.  ILE languages on the i don't include the parameter list as part of any "signature" stored with the *SRVPGM object.

Longer answer, you should have external prototype for the procedures in your service program that are `/COPY` into both the service program module that has the procedures and any programs that are using them.

If your *SRVPGM object was compiled with DBGVIEW(*LIST), then you can look at source as compiled with the debugger.

Lastly, there's a relatively new option to generate Program interface Information, aka PCML when the service program module is compiled and store it in either a stream file or the module object itself.
`CRTRPGMOD ... PGMINFO(*PCML *MODULE)`

This PCML information is normally just used by the Integrated Web Services (IWS) server.  But IBM as published an [example program](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/1118271) that will display it from a command line.